# Connection not secure warning when connecting to .onion domain with Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

I have self-hosted Discourse based forum, available over .onion domain only (Hidden Service Version 3). Everything works as expected, however when I connect to the forum with an up to date version of Tor Browser I can see an exclamation mark on the onion icon in the address bar, similar to what you can sometimes see when you have mixed content error with clearnet https connection.

When I click on the exclamation mark I can see actual warning saying:

"Connection not secure. Parts of this page are not secure (such as images)".

It looks like similar to https error, however my forum does not use https in urls, there is no certificates added etc. I have no clue, what does it mean in the world of onion domains. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that your onion service has HTTP content from a non-onion address. For example, maybe your website abc.onion has images from http://example.com.

Comment: You are probably right, however, the only non-onion link I found in a website HTML is in the line <div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/"..>. Another interesting thing is that the warning appeared to show up randomly from time to time only (the link was present all the time) and I haven't seen it from some time now, despite no congifuration has been changed.